# List странно работает

Tags: python, python-3.x, telebot

Я тут делаю 1-го бота на pytelegramBotAPI.
Мне нужно, чтобы бот получил название объекта при написании /start, а потом через `next_step_handler` получал цену и всё это записывал в список `list`, и потом его print'овал. Всё то готово, но возникли проблемы со списком `list`: он не выводит полными словами (название) или цифрами (цена), а выводит по символам. После теста, `print` выдал:

```python
['Б', 'о', 'н', 'с', 'а', 'й', '2', '0', '0', '0'].
```

Хотя ожидался результат такого вида:

```python
['Бонсай', '2000']
```

Код (рабочий, и протещенный):

```python
    import telebot
    bot = telebot.TeleBot('')
    import sqlite3
    conn = sqlite3.connect('nb.db', check_same_thread = False)
    c = conn.cursor()

    @bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
    def start(message):
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "Хорошо.. название, к примеру:\nЯпонский Бонсай")
        bot.register_next_step_handler(call.message, Costmerch)
    def Costmerch(message):
        merch = []
        merch += message.text
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Теперь же, цена. Минимум - 1000, Максимум - 10000000')
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, Costmerch, merch)
    def Costmerchprint(message, merch):
        merch += message.text
        print(merch)
```

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей. См. Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример в справке.

Comment: (У Вас не хватает, по крайней мере, ожидаемого поведения)

Comment: Простите, стак удалил начало моего вопроса. Уже который раз приходится редактировать

Comment: Его удалил я, а не "стак", потому что фраза *как живётся? у меня тут проблемки* не имеет отношения к сути. И моя правка никак не поменяла тот факт, что ожидаемое поведение в вопросе не описано.

Comment: Всё, изменил вопрос

Comment: Может я глупый или туплю с недосыпа, но можно наглядный пример, как должен выглядеть правильный вывод?

Comment: Ну, допустим ['Бонсай', '2000'], потому что хочу добавлять в БД, а если так собрать переменную (как сделал мой код). то SqLite не поймёт, а мне этого не нужно;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавление элемента в список так, как Вы этого ожидаете делается с помощью метода `append`, а не оператора `+=`. Измените Вашу строку кода на следующую:

```python
merch.append(message.text)
```

А оператор `+=` для операндов типов `list` и `str` работает именно так, как Вы продемонстрировали в "неверном" варианте, виноват не "бамбук", а стандарт языка, в котором описана такая работа.

Comment: @YDCdeveloper, всегда рад помочь. Кстати, если Вы хотите, чтобы каждому объекту соответствовала его цена, `list` – не лучший выбор. Попробуйте `dict`.